# Export Specific Columns from Excel to Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, closedxml

I have a spreadsheet with 120 columns and about 800 rows of data. I found the code below online and it works great,  using ClosedXml.

Instead of exporting all the rows using I want to just grab cols 1 & 2 (and their headers) and also col's 15 thru 46  with their corresponding headers.

Does anyone know if ClosedXml as a call/procedure to extract specific columns or will I need to put the desired columns in an Array and then pull what's needed from there? I've wore google out looking :) .

Thanks

```
Protected Sub ImportExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
    Using workBook As New XLWorkbook(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        'Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
        Dim workSheet As IXLWorksheet = workBook.Worksheet(1)
 
        'Create a new DataTable.
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
 
        'Loop through the Worksheet rows.
        Dim firstRow As Boolean = True
        For Each row As IXLRow In workSheet.Rows()
            'Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
            If firstRow Then
                For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString())
                Next
                firstRow = False
            Else
                'Add rows to DataTable.
                dt.Rows.Add()
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
                    dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value.ToString()
                    i += 1
                Next
            End If
 
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `GetColumnNames` I get names by selecting a range from the Excel sheet. It would be A1:P1 but replace P with the whatever the last column is.

```
Private strFileName As String = "C:\Users\..." 'Your path with file name
Private ConStr As String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={strFileName};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""

Private Function GetColumnNames() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sheetname = "Vanguard"
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM [{sheetname}$A1:P1]", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

In the `GetSelectQuery` I take the `DataTable` with the column names and add only the columns we are interested in to a list. Using `String.Join` to get a single comma delimited string which is inserted into the Select statement.

```
Private Function GetSelectQuery() As String
    Dim sheetname = "Vanguard"
    Dim dt = GetColumnNames()
    Dim fields As New List(Of String)
    'Add the first 2 field names to the list
    For i = 0 To 1
        fields.Add(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
    Next
    'Add fields 15 - 46
    For i = 7 To 10
        fields.Add(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
    Next
    Dim StringOfFieldNames = String.Join(",", fields)
    Dim SelectQuery = $"Select {StringOfFieldNames} From [{sheetname}$];"
    Debug.Print(SelectQuery) 'Just to check if the Select statement looks correct
    Return SelectQuery
End Function
```

In the Button.Click use the Select query to fill a `DataTable` and assign it as `DataSource` to a grid.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SelectQuery = GetSelectQuery()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mary :)

You gave me the nudge I needed. What I did was just search the existing dataset already populated with all the columns(119) and Rows(444). I built another datatable and populated
with the col's and rows I wanted and bound that to my datagridview. I was trying not to use Oledb because my clients have a variety of machines and was running into issues with the old microsoft.oledb.16.0 provider not registered issue.  Here's the added code below.
Next I'll wrap all param list into an array of some sort to condense the code a little.

Thanks again for your help :)

```
    Dim dtmeanavg As New DataTable("meanavg")

        For i = 0 To 1
            dtmeanavg.Columns.Add(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
        Next

        For i = 15 To 40
            dtmeanavg.Columns.Add(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
        Next

        For i = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            dtmeanavg.Rows.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(0),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(1),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(2),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(15),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(16),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(17),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(18),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(19),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(20),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(21),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(22),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(23),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(24),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(25),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(26),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(27),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(28),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(29),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(30),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(31),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(32),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(33),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(34),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(35),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(36),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(37),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(38),
                            dt.Rows(i).Item(39)
                                        )
        Next




        dgvInventory.DataSource = dtmeanavg
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
        workBook.Dispose()
```